# How to call variable with input string

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, variable-names

This is my problem:

I want to make a input that will run the name of the variable that is input.

```
var = "working!"
cmd = input(":")
#I want it so that the user inputs "var", the var variable ("working!") is printed.
#But if I put the print like it is below, it will print a string of what is input. So, it will print "var".
print(cmd)
```

Essentially, I want something that turns the input string into a variable name, so I can call said variable.

Comment: You run/call a function, not a variable

Comment: `print(globals()[cmd])`

Comment: Find your favourite python tutorial on 'dictionaries' for one easy way to this.

Comment: @NickA that is both clever and awful.

Comment: @pvg agreed! :)

Comment: I would prefer `locals()[input(':')]`

Comment: Try [`from __past__ import input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: This is turning into some sort of competition for 'worst possible answer for a beginner'.

Answer (score -6):

You need to use the eval() function:

```
var = "working!"
print(eval("var"))
```

Comment: This is generally considered dangerous, and it's unnecessary as it can be done with a dictionary, or if access to variables is paramount, with `globals`, without compromising your code.